# How to get observable value property from observable array?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that is to take an array of observable locations, filter them based on a locationid parameter, and then return the location name for that specific location based on that locationid. How do I use pipe, map, filter and subscribe to get this specific value? The function name is getLocationForEquipment.

```
import { LocationService } from 'src/app/services/location.service';
import { Equipment } from 'src/app/models/equipment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { EquipmentService } from 'src/app/services/equipment.service';
import { RentService } from 'src/app/services/rent.service';
import { AccountService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { Location } from 'src/app/models/location';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    loading: boolean = false;
    submitted: boolean = false;
    openQrCode: boolean = false;
    enterPinCode: boolean = false;
    QrCode!: string;
  equipments: Observable<Equipment[]>
  locations!: Observable<Location[]>

    constructor(
    public locationService: LocationService,
        public accountService: AccountService,
    public equipmentService: EquipmentService,
    public rentService: RentService,
  ) {
    this.equipments = equipmentService.getAllEquipment(this.accountService.user.organizationid)
    this.locations = locationService.getAllLocations(this.accountService.user.organizationid)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getLocationForEquipment(equipid: number) {
    this.locations.pipe (
      map(items => {      
        items.filter(item => item.id === equipid)
      }
  ))}

  onOpenQrScanner() {
    this.openQrCode = true;
  }

  scanSuccessHandler(scanValue: string) {
    console.log(scanValue)
    this.enterPinCode = true;
    this.QrCode = scanValue;
    console.log(scanValue)
    return this.scanSuccessHandler
  }

  scanErrorHandler(scanError: any) {
    console.log(scanError)
  }


}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item-group>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let equipment of equipments | async">
      <ion-card-title class="class-title">{{getLocationForEquipment(equipment.locationid)}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle class="class-subtitle">{{equipment.description}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-item-group>
```

```
export class Location {
  id!: number;
  organizationid!: number;
  name!: string;
  description!: string;
  active!: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would want multiple ion-cards for each equipment.

First rename your observables to something like

`equipments$` and `locations$`. That makes it easier to separate Observables from actual values (Read more about that naming convention here: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables)

Second you need to change your get Location function:

```
  getLocationForEquipment(equipid: number, locations: Location[]): Location {
    return locations.find(item => item.id === equipid);
  }
```

I exchanged filter for find, since you really want only one value. Additionally I added a return type to make it clear what we are returning. Also there is the new parameter locations, which are the current received locations

Third change your HTML to:

```
<ion-item-group 
    *ngIf="{
      equipments: equipments$ | async
      locations: locations$ | async
    } as observables"
>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let equipment of (observables.equipments || [])">
      <ion-card-title class="class-title" *ngIf="observables.locations">{{getLocationForEquipment(equipment.locationid, observables.locations)?.name}} </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle class="class-subtitle">{{equipment.description}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-item-group>
```

Since your observable holds array values, you need to iterate over the value the observable returns. To get the value out of the observable I usually use `*ngIf` to declare a variable and show nothing until the observable fired. In this case we want the values of both observables, so I create a temporary object holding the current observable values. Then use `*ngFor` to iterate over the equipment array. Lastly we need to call `getLocationForEquipment` which needs the current locationId and all locations.

Since I wasn't sure how a Location-Object looks like I just used the arbitrary field 'name' to give an example on how to display fields.

p.s. tell me if this code works, or if you get any error since I was too lazy to actually run this code. Just implemented it in the browser lol

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get the following error on my function with your solution:

Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Location>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Location'.ts(2322)

Comment: Ah, sorry I had one too many brackets in the getLocationForEquipment function. I fixed it!

Comment: I now get a infinite error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name'), even though I have defined the name in the location model.

Comment: Damit should've run the code after all lol. Anyways the problem was, that the async pipe initially returns a null value. I fixed it by adding a `?` to the HTML part where I access the name

Comment: I get an insane amount of calls now towards location. Not sure why they are stuck in an infinite loop, is it something to do with these async pipes? And the *NgIf *ngIf="equipments async as equipments" in the start returns  Property 'async' does not exist on type 'NgIfContext<Observable<Equipment[]>>'.

Comment: And do I not need to subscribe on the operator in the function?

Comment: So sorry for making so many mistakes. I restructured the code. You might need to add a null check, I wasn't sure. Async internally subscribes so you don't need to do it by hand. However since I had async in a loop, I created a lot of subscriptions, each recreated, when the change detection happend (so indefinitely since they trigger a change). To fix this I put both async pipes to do them only once. I really hope it works as expected now!

Comment: added the nullcheck I was worried about for observables.equipments. Final edit I promise!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252616/discussion-between-maffe-and-berse2212).